# r why if_else converted character to numbers and how to keep character

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I had character variables in my dataset and after if_else they were converted to numbers while I need them to be characters (later I will convert them to factors).
Does anyone know how to fix it?

I had these lines of code

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    flag_elevator = if_else(elevator_type == 'nincs megadva'|is.na(elevator_type), 1, 0),
    elevator_type = if_else(elevator_type == 'van', 1, 0))
```

Comment: Add quotes around 1 and 0

Comment: You could also fix this by using `ifelse` instead of `if_else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as @AshishSinghal suggested:

```
if_else(elevator_type == 'van', '1', '0')
```

Or since it is 0/1 you can do away with the if_else:

```
data = data.frame(elevator_type = sample(c('nincs megadva','van',NA),100,replace=TRUE))

tibble(data) %>%
mutate(
flag_elevator = +(elevator_type == 'nincs megadva'|is.na(elevator_type)),
elevator_type = as.character(+(elevator_type == 'van')))
```